# camera pose: partial view/multiple markers solution

Tags: c++, python, opencv, artoolkit

I'm new to OpenCV and my question is the following:

What is the best way to obtain the camera coordinates when I won't have a full view of my scene ?

What I mean is that I need to move the camera around an object and at each frame be able to find the camera coordinates.

Should I use multiple markers, try to recognize them and then proceed to the coordinates calculation using the solvePNP function ? If so, how can I do it ? Any recommendations ?

By the way, I'm using OpenCV with python, I already tried the ARToolKit library but it was just impossible to install it..

If no solutions exist for OpenCV-Python, I'm open for a OpenCV-C++ based one.

Thank you !

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your reply! If MatLab could offer a solution I think I could use it. This question was asked at the beginning of my master Thesis, meanwhile the project changed a lot and it turned out I used a Kinect camera to get the pose in real time. Thx for your interest tho ! :)